# how does one get a value from hidden field repeater without through invalid post back

Tags: c#, file-io, webforms

I am trying to use a inline pdf browser but when i call the code it says the following error

> invvalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

I saw that on most forms it recomends not to disable the above and to use RegisterForEventValidation but my question is how do I enable if for a button inside a repeater I have tried the following but its not fiding my button method

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(btnViewDocumentBrowser_Click);
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

This is the code to render the pdf in browser that is causing the above exception

```
protected void btnDownloadDocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)rptDocumentsProposal.FindControl("currentFileName");

    if (hf != null)
    {
        string filename = hf.Value.ToString();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attach;filename=" + filename);
        Response.TransmitFile(filename);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Code for repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDocumentsProposal" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-6 sidesthick">
            <div class="windowbox">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <h2><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("documentTitle") %>' /></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right icon-doc">
                    <asp:Label ID="IconDocument" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        Name:
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("documentTitle") %>' />
                        <br /> Description:
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("documentDescription") %>' />
                        <br /> Type:
                        <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("type") %>' />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="currentFileName" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "serverPath") %>' runat="server" />
                        <br />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="center">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDownloadDocument" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="btnDownloadDocument_Click" runat="server" Text="Download Document" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnViewDocumentBrowser" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("serverPath") %>' CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="btnViewDocumentBrowser_Click" runat="server" Text="View In Browser" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The bit appears to be causing probelm is the `HiddenField` when im trying to find it its not finding the correct file name even though one is populated within that repeater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get the item inside`Repeater` as simple as that, you need to do that like this:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptDocumentsProposal.Items)
{
    var hf = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("currentFileName");
    // now you access to hf.Value
    // btw please you hfCurrentFileName instead of just currentFileName as your HiddenField name :)
}
```

So, that is for the finding `HiddenField` issue.

For dealing with `Button's click`, I recommended to use `Repeater's OnItemCommand event` instead of `Button's OnClick event`. using `OnItemCommand` is very easy and you separate the `OnClick event` of `normal used Buttons` and `inside Repeater used Buttons` (*hope you get the point*).

So, here is the code:

*You need to add `OnItemCommand` to **Repeater**, like this:*

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDocumentsProposal" runat="server"
    OnItemCommand="rptDocumentsProposal_ItemCommand">
```

*Also `CommandName` & `CommandArgument` to the `Button`, like this:*

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDownloadDocument" runat="server"
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SOME_VALUE") %>' CommandName="Download" />
```

*And finally **C#***

```
protected void rptDocumentsProposal_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandArgument == null)
        return;

    // I prefer to use switch/case here to handle more Buttons click easily
    // feel free to use if/else instead of switch/case
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Download":
            // deal with the Button click here
            break;

        default:
            // hello !!, there is nothing to do with
            break;
    }
}
```

BTW, I got your mentioned error, when I trying to change `ASP controls` value with `JS` and send back them to server.

*I didn't see anything like this in your shared code, so I think you will win with this way.* :)

try this solution (*if you like*) and report the result.